# Select image from specific folder Android

Tags: android, uri

Hi i want to get image from a specific folder. Now im using this code:

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Scegli foto"),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

Now,with that uri i see the recent and i have to open manually folder.I've tryed setting uri.parse input with the path of my folder,but i got anyway my recent.How can i open automatically my folder?

Answer (score 0):

try this my friend

```
    private void getImages() {
    String[] filenames = new String[0];
    File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/FolderName");
    if (path.exists()) {
        filenames = path.list();
    }
    ArrayList<String> imagesPathArrayList;

    for (int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
        imagesPathArrayList.add(path.getPath() + "/" + filenames[i]);
        Log.e("FAV_Images", imagesPathArrayList.get(i));
        ///Now set this bitmap on imageview
    }
}
```

**set image like this**

```
Bitmap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagesPathArrayList.get(position));
ImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: How can i choose one of the file in the arraylist?